# How to show a value present inside a function inside the body property in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making an app that requires me to use an ml model and is performing its calculation to get the output from the ml model inside a function, now I need to display that constant which stores the final output of that ml model inside the body property of my swift UI view so that I can present it inside Text() maybe and modify the way it looks Lil bit
all of this code is inside a single swift file

here is all the code

[image: image 1]

[image: rest of the code]

after making the changes it's still showing some error

```
struct newView: View {
    
    let model = AudiCar()
    
    @ObservedObject var values: impData
   @State var price = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text("calculated price is " + price)
                    .onAppear {
                        calculatePrice()
    }

    func calculatePrice() {  <- this is where it showing error, saying " Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder' " 
        
       do {
        let AudiCarOutput =  try model.prediction(model: String(values.nameSelection), year: Double(values.yearSelection), transmission: String(values.transmisssionSelec), mileage: Double(values.mileage), fuelType: String(values.fuelSelection))
            
           let price = String(AudiCarOutput.price)

       }

       catch {

       }
 
    }

   
}

struct newView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        newView(values: impData())
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question instead (+ format it with the code format thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
struct NewView: View {
    let model = AudiCar()
    @ObservevedObject var values: impData
    
    @State var price = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("calculated price is " + price)
            .onAppear {
                calculatePrice()
            }
    }
    
    func calculatePrice() {
        do {
            ...
           price = String(AudiCarOutput.price)
        }
        catch {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's actually throwing an error for the function now, saying  " Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'  "

Comment: show us the (text) code you are using, including how you use "NewView", and the place where the error occurs. Something that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: i have edited the question with the changes I made suggested by you please see to it

Comment: you have to put "func calculatePrice()" outside of the "body" like in my answer, not inside. Look carefully at your "}". It should then work. Let us know.

Comment: i did that and then i run the app but the price is not showing, just the text is appearing "the calculated price is"

Comment: @aadityaaa, you are not listening, do something like my answer. Do not use "let price = String(AudiCarOutput.price)" this will not work. Do as I did, "price = String(AudiCarOutput.price)". Edit you question, and show the code you are using now.

Comment: am sorry I did not see it earlier, thanks a lot, it works now!!